# Boostrapped sample missing covariate levels

Tags: regression, categorical-data, bootstrap

I'm running a regression model and using bootstrapping to generate standard errors for a binary predictor because the distribution of the estimator of its effect is unknown. I have a large sample, but few observations take one of the values of the predictor, so in bootstrap samples, the number of observations that take that value can be unacceptably small or even zero. What should I do in these cases?

A thought I had was to resample within levels of the predictor, so that the number of observations in each category is stable across bootstrap sample. Is this a sensible thing to do? I have also heard that I can simply throw out bootstrap samples that don't meet certain data qualities (e.g., have 0 observations in a category), but this seems like it would bias the results.